# Maui How to close modal page?

Tags: navigation, maui

From a page I call a modal page.
In the modal page is a form and two button "cancel" and "submit".
After clicking one button the modal should close and the previous page should be visible.

**How I have to handle the modal page click event to close the modal page?**

(Or what is the standard way to close a modal page?

My page codebehind:

```
private async void Btn7_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new ModalPage());
}
```

My ModalPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Mandatos.Views.ModalPage"
         Title="ModalPage">
<VerticalStackLayout Margin="50">
    <Label Text="Example form" FontSize="30" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
    <Grid WidthRequest="600" Margin="0, 30">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Text="Input 1:" VerticalTextAlignment="End"/>
        <Entry Grid.Column="2" />

        <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="Input 2:" VerticalTextAlignment="End"/>
        <Entry Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" />

        <Label Grid.Row="2" Text="Input 3:" VerticalTextAlignment="End"/>
        <Entry  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"/>

        <Label Grid.Row="3" Text="Input 4:" VerticalTextAlignment="End"/>
        <Entry  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" />

    </Grid>

    <Grid WidthRequest="600" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Text="Cancel"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="Submit"/>
    </Grid>

</VerticalStackLayout>
```

ModalPage codebehind:

```
public partial class ModalPage : ContentPage
{
 public ModalPage()
 {
    InitializeComponent();
 }

 private void CancelButton_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {   //...???  }

 private void SubmitButton_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {   //...???  }
}
```

Comment: Use `PopModalAsync`

Comment: @Jason Yes, I also found this alternative from communtytoolkit.maui. I would still find it interesting. ;-) Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer on the modal page is:

```
await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
```

at my example:

```
private async void CancelButton_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
}

private async void SubmitButton_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
}
```

I found the answer here:
[learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/modal)